# Angular can't parse Spring response

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, angularjs, spring-boot

I am having some issues trying to receive a response message from a Spring RESTful web service to an AngularJS client.

I am using `ResponseEntity<String>` to return a response to the client. This works when only returning a status code but AngularJS fails with `Unexpected token R` when I send a response message in the body.

What am I doing wrong?

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
```

But this does not work:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>("Report was updated successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
```

AngularJs code:

```
$http.get(url, header)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // some logic
    }).error(function(resp, status) {
        // some logic
    });
```

Response:

[image: Screen Capture]

Answer (score 1):

Is Angular expecting JSON or HTML/text back?

I've experienced issues in the past returning text/javascript or application/json instead of text/html. It looks like Angular is expecting JSON or JSONP in that instance, hence the Unexpected Token R (which is the first letter of your response string).

I could give a more precise answer, but I'd need to also know if you're using JSONP vs JSON, etc.

Comment: I have tried with both headers so far, `application/json` and `text/plain` but not luck as of yet. I am not too familiar with Angularjs and I am still going through a learning process, so I am not sure if it is JSON or JSONP, I am just using default Angular $http config I suppose.

Comment: You could try formatting the message as: {"data": "Report was updated successfully"} and see if that passes?

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a workaround, I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know. Thanks

Comment: So the workaround has worked. I created a custom `Message` object that contains a string message variable. A cheap and dirty solution - but a solution none the less!